# Set manually the map scale on tmap

Tags: tmap

I am creating a map with `tmap` to plot specific coordinates as dots.
I would like to save my map as .png and this works well using `tmap_leaflet` and `mapshot` (see code below).

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(mapview)

coord <- data.frame(Lat=c(0.92, 0.92, 0.93, 0.92, 0.93, 0.93, 1.00, 1.00, 0.99, 0.93),
              Lon=c(104.58, 104.51, 104.57, 104.50, 104.55, 104.51, 104.59, 104.49, 104.6, 104.61))
sdat <- st_as_sf(coord, coords = c("Lon", "Lat"),
                 crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
tmap_mode("view")
Map <- tm_basemap("Esri.WorldTopoMap") +
  tm_shape(sdat) +
  tm_dots(alpha = 1,
          title = "Location")
lf <- tmap_leaflet(Map)
mapshot(lf, file = "Map.png") # save map
```

My issue is the default area that gets visualized in tmap view mode.
I would like to zoom out to visualise a larger area of the map (setting specific boundaries for instance) and not only the area really close to the points plotted. I couldn't find a solution online yet.
This is how I get the .png:
[image]

And this is what I would like to get for instance (made with a screenshot):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the zoom levels using `tm_view()`:

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(mapview)

coord <- data.frame(Lat=c(0.92, 0.92, 0.93, 0.92, 0.93, 0.93, 1.00, 1.00, 0.99, 0.93),
              Lon=c(104.58, 104.51, 104.57, 104.50, 104.55, 104.51, 104.59, 104.49, 104.6, 104.61))
sdat <- st_as_sf(coord, coords = c("Lon", "Lat"),
                 crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
tmap_mode("view")
Map <- tm_basemap("Esri.WorldTopoMap") +
  tm_shape(sdat) +
  tm_dots(alpha = 1,
          title = "Location") +
  tm_view(set.zoom.limits = c(10, 20))

lf <- tmap_leaflet(Map)
mapshot(lf, file = "Map.png")
```

[image]